# customize toolbar position and customize ckeditor javascript file

Tags: ckeditor4.x

i am using ckeditor inline , i want to customize ckeditor toolbar top and left position once toolbar is loaded at certain position. and also i want to update ckeditor.js and use in my website but when i edit ckeditor.js using beautifier , it gives error after i update and use in website.

i have tried to set custom top and left position for ckeditor toolbar but as it comes out from instanceReady event , it again reset position .

```
               ck = CKEDITOR.inline(editableDivElement[0], {
                removePlugins: 'resize, elementspath',
                extraPlugins: 'ckeditor_wiris, smiley',
                height: 60,
                toolbar: toolbars,
                toolbarLocation: 'top',
                startupFocus: true,
              });


                  ck.on("instanceReady", function (event) {
                    var ckeditorToolBar: any = 
                    document.getElementsByClassName("cke");
                     if (ckeditorToolBar) {
                        ckeditorToolBar[0].style.top ="100px";
                       ckeditorToolBar[0].style.left="100px";
                   });
```

if there is way i can edit ckeditor.js and use in my website and also if i can set custom ckeditor toolbar position using top and left.

Comment: In CKEditor toolbar, we have a default Id cke_top, if you want to add any CSS you can use this Id

Comment: yes after i set custom position in instanceReady event using above code left and top,but ckeditor over rides top and left position on events. so kindly if you know how can i prevent setting custom toolbar position and i can keep position dynamically and ckeditor doesn't over rides it.

Comment: This is not a good way. but if need just add important for CSS and you can overwrite default  CSS

Comment: okay thanks i got it work by css. but i found one more issue in firefox , ckeditor gets focused  but cursor not displayed and still on typing it works with invisible cursor. then again if i click some where and focus on ckeditor then cursor get displayed.